# how to solve the problem about cross k function in R

Tags: spatstat

I was using kcross to study the cluster of restaurant and parking in Toronto, and got some error.
this is part of my data:
type    X   Y
restaurant  43.75409    -79.34955
restaurant  43.67074    -79.39139
restaurant  43.64289    -79.42543
restaurant  43.70423    -79.38823
restaurant  43.66618    -79.31647
restaurant  43.63844    -79.41724
restaurant  43.69279    -79.26263
restaurant  43.64171    -79.43219
restaurant  43.64759    -79.39203
restaurant  43.6449 -79.39172
restaurant  43.74256    -79.31425
restaurant  43.67272    -79.31957
restaurant  43.73177    -79.40398
restaurant  43.60052    -79.50552
restaurant  43.64961    -79.38545
restaurant  43.6576 -79.48768
restaurant  43.66622    -79.38525
restaurant  43.67066    -79.39407
restaurant  43.67383    -79.46274
restaurant  43.65371    -79.37582
restaurant  43.64884    -79.38
restaurant  43.68849    -79.39322
restaurant  43.73679    -79.43852
restaurant  43.64932    -79.37841
parking 43.63543    -79.53902
parking 43.68638    -79.59816
parking 43.67502    -79.56266
parking 43.64446    -79.52602
parking 43.64664    -79.531
parking 43.64254    -79.52758
parking 43.64538    -79.5328
parking 43.66137    -79.55822
parking 43.68551    -79.5847
parking 43.76722    -79.49017
parking 43.59695    -79.51113
parking 43.60013    -79.50408
parking 43.60022    -79.50412
parking 43.60027    -79.50413
parking 43.60098    -79.50692
parking 43.60126    -79.50511
parking 43.61326    -79.49269
parking 43.61487    -79.48946
parking 43.62314    -79.51992
parking 43.61739    -79.49624
parking 43.6257 -79.50352
parking 43.6269 -79.50251

```
#kcrossparkingrestaurant
REPA <- read.csv("REPA.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
WREPA <- ripras(REPA)

types <- factor(REPA$type)
REPA <- ppp(x = REPA$X, y = REPA$Y,window = WREPA,marks=types)
KREPA <- Kcross(REPA, i = "restaurant", j = "parking")
plot(KREPA)
```

Comment: Please include the relevant data in a standard format. You can use the function `dput` in R to get a format you can copy/paste into a code block and make the example reproducible. Please work on your example/question and make it into a reproducible script that can be run in a clean R session and generate the error you get. You can potentially use the package `reprex` to format the example nicely for StackOverflow (use `venue = "so"`). Good luck improving your question :-)

Comment: You say that you "got some error". What error was that?